# Creating a URL with XML

Tags: android, xml, url

I've searched and searched and can't seem to find any tutorial on how to write my own webpage that is strictly XML. [This](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml) is the sort of thing I want to create myself. I'm not too advanced of an XML or webpage writer, but does anyone have any ideas/tutorials?

P.S.  I want to do this because I'm writing an android app that needs to pull information from this XML file.  A local XML file is not a solution.  A requirement for this app is that the XML *needs* to be online.

P.S.S.  Here's a small sample of what I'd like to write to a URL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Phone Numbers Set 1 -->
    <string name="police1_phone">555-555-5555</string>
    <string name="police2_phone">555-555-5555</string>
    <string name="police3_phone">555-555-5555</string>
    <string name="police4_phone">555-555-5555</string>
    <string name="police5_phone">555-555-5555</string>

    <!-- Phone Numbers Set 2 -->
    <string name="fire1_phone">555-555-5555</string>
    <string name="fire2_phone">555-555-5555</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't find any tutorial because you're mixing things here. An URL is an Universal Resouce Locator, which means it can point to anything (not just HTML files). Just put your XML in your server and use the path as URL, it will be fine.

If you need any more clarifications, just let me know

Comment: But the problem is, I need this XML file to be global.  The app is intended for several users across town to be able to use the app.  Also, I later intend to add an 'update' button to the app, so that if I ever update this XML file (i.e. a phone number of a company changes, etc.), the user can hit update and the app will begin reading the updated XML file from the URL/link/HTTP/thing.

Comment: If users cannot modify the XML, still no problem. The XML is global and public if you set the URL to be so on the server. If you modify the XML, the users will see the modified XML. No URL changes are needed, since the XML didn't move.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by others, XML is not the same as a URL.  However, I understand what you're looking for.  Typically, when writing a web-page, you have a .html file that will display whatever code you've written in there.  If you just paste your XML code into that .html file and display that, it will show your raw XML code.

Answer (score 0):

Well you acutally should call a webservice which returns information in form of xml !

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the XML data to remain the same or change depending on some factor? If it stays the same, just put all of the XML data into an .xml file, upload it to your server and link to that. If you want to generate XML, you'll need to write a script that spits out the desired XML data every time someone visits that page.

Comment: I want to be able to edit it so that the app can read fresh, updated data from this url thing, no matter who is using the app.

Comment: Whenever you save any changes to the XML file on your server, anything that tries to access that URL will see the new version of the file immediately.

A URL is a pointer to something. That something the URL points to can change at any time, it can even disappear if deleted. When the contents of your XML file change, the URL can stay the same and refer to the new contents of your XML file.